# Sculpting - Unwanted lines on brush strokes

Tags: sculpt

[image]

While sculpting, I get these lines on my brush strokes. This particluar example was made with Clay Strips. With other brushes it's not as noticeable, but it's there too.
I don't know if this happens because of some limitation of Blender itself, since the model has a lot of polygons (720k tris), and it may be "lagging".
Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the object scale applied? (Object mode > Ctrl+A). It depends on mesh size of course but 720k tris should be plenty enough to sculpt forms shown on the screenshot without any troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, it may be because of the low resolution.  Usually with Sculpting Mode, you'll want to use the Multiresolution modifier so that in sculpting mode you can have a high resolution while in object mode the resolution won't slow you down too much.  You can also check you brush settings, particularly Texture and Symmetry/Lock.  In Stroke settings, you can make sure that the spacing is set to 1% and the jitter to 0.

Comment: Setting the Stroke spacing to 1% fixed it. Thanks so much for the help, This was driving me nuts! :)